# Are single threaded applications thread safe

Tags: vb.net

I understand the concept of multi threaded apartments i.e. if an object is created by one thread then it can be used in all other threads.

I have read that there is one multi threaded Apartment per process.  In ASP.NET there is generally one W3WP.exe process for IIS.  Therefore how does IIS distinguish between objects created in one session or one application by one user and objects created by another session by another user? I assume that the Session Object and Application object is used but I am unclear and would like to know if there are other mechanisms.

Also how do worker Threads and I/O threads fit into this concept? i.e. if I have a program that does not create any threads of its own (using System.Threading.Thread) and does not use any third party libraries other than those part of the .NET framework, then I assume that all of the code in the program is Thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

When your dealing with a standard FORMS or CMD Line application, assuming you do not create any explicit threads and do not use any components that imply a seperate thread like background worker, you are operating on the primary application thread for all your normally entered user code. The system will create other threads to do various things to support your application but for all intensive purposes you can consider it thread-safe. There other threads would be part of otehr components and should already be coded in a safe fashion to interact without any conflicts or cross threading issues.

In ASP.NET this is different as you noted. IIS doesn't really care, beyond a specific Page, about objects you created. Your main thread is for a given request and really the main object is the "page", anything stored in the page is in this sort of sheltered space where no conflict can really coour. Also the Session Object, this is Page specific and as issolated to the specific request as possible and therfore safe. There is never one Page or Session object exposed to another but the pages are all in the same application and technically could be seen by each other (unless you did some extremely strange coding that would definitly be very, very bad).

What becomes unsafe to a larger degree is Application objects. If you store an object in Application space and use it in multiple page requests you need to make sure whatever your doing to the object doesn't have a possible conflict with another request which could be processed in a parrallel request. An example of this could be storing a Static DataTable of items in application space. I would not normally do this however if you had to a safe way to deal with it is to use a syncronization object to not allow code from one request/thread from overlapping this object.
Also note that Application object/space is effectively the same as Public Module Space in VB.Net, I use a module to show example below...

**Example** *(This is very over simplified and not something I would normally do in code it is to explain the SYNCLOCK mechanizm only)*

```
Public Module SharedSpace

    ' what object is used as a syncronizer is irrelavent, just needs defined only once at the start of the application.
    Public SyncDT As New Exception("none")

    Public dt As DataTable

End Module

Public Class PageItem
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        SyncLock SyncDT
' ...
' work with "dt" ONLY inside the synclock space
' SyncLock blocks can be anywhere but they need to be as short as possible.
' Any code running in another page request will STOP trying to enter the SyncLock (for the object specified) 
' and waits until any existing SyncLock on the same object is released by exiting the SyncLock.
' ...
        End SyncLock

    End Sub

End Class
```

Effectively as long as "dt" is only access inside a block with "Synclock SyncDT" it is safe across multiple threads. However it is UNACCEPTABLE to access "dt" without a SyncLock in this fashion since an overlap could occur.

There are other thread marshalling objects in .NET, Synclock is my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Single  threaded process is not thread-safe guaranteed.
If a process received a signal, and the process stop when access some critical data, and the single handler also access that critical data, then it's not thread-safe.